# Getting year of timestamp in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have table called `TrainingMatrix` and it has a column called `ExpiryDate`. I am trying to write an SQL statement which can show me all records of 2012 as following:

```
 SELECT * FROM "TrainingMatrix" WHERE "ExpiryDate" - current_date < 0 AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIMESTAMP "ExpiryDate") = 2012;
```

But this doesn't work, can any one help?

I am using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No *timestamp* word when using column:

```
... AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "ExpiryDate") = 2012 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have index on ExpiryDate column - it's better to avoid using functions and have exact date/timestamp range:

```
and "ExpiryDate">='2012-01-01' and "ExpiryDate"<'2013-01-01';
```